# JTDS error: Native SSPI library not loaded

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jtds

I've seen this question come up multiple times, but all the answers I've tried haven't worked for me. The Connection string used to look like this

```
url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server1/dbname;user=user;password=pswd"; //this one works fine
url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server1;dbname;databaseName=dbname;integratedSecurity=true"; //doesn't work
```

but I am getting the exception.

```
java.io.IOException: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.
```

I have jtds 1.2, and I copied the ntlmauth.dll to my lib folder, and on eclipse added the path to the Native library location for the jtd-1.2.jar, but nothing changed.

Also tried adding -Djava.library.path=./lib to my run configuration. I'm running an RCP application with jre 1.7 and Eclipse Helios

Comment: I've also added the ntlmauth.dll to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

Answer (score 0):

I made my program work by using the Microsfot JDBC driver instead. Downloaded from their website

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

and removed jtds from the connection string

```
url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server1;dbname;databaseName=dbname;integratedSecurity=true";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Normally I would do something like this, which works fine:

```
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnection, "username", "pasword");
```

But when trying to get the username and password from a method like this:

```
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnection, getUser(), getPassword());
```

I was getting the same error. It turned out that `getUser()` was returning `null`, which seems to have made SQL Server try using Windows Authentication to log in, which wasn't set up on that machine. So making sure `getUser()` wasn't `null` made the difference.